# Convert List<Product> to Map<Integer, List<Product>>

Tags: java, list, collections, dictionary

Could you assume to me the best or more ellegant way, to convert 
`List<Product>` allProducts to `Map<Integer, List<Product>>` products grouped by ProductNumber.

For example my Product POJO.

```
public class Product{
.. 
private Integer productCode;
private String productName;
...
//getters, setters
}
```

This is my try, But I think it not so ellegant:

```
public Map<Integer, List<Product>> getProductsByIndex (List<Product> products){
        Map<Integer, List<Product>> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
        Set<Integer> productCodes = getProductCodes(products);

        for(Integer productCode: productCodes){
            List<Product> productsByCode = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Product product : products){
                if(productCode == product.getCode()){
                    productsByCode.add(product);    
                }
            }
            resultMap.put(productCode, productsByCode);
        }
        return resultMap;
    }

    public Set<Integer> getProductCodes (List<Product> products){
        Set<Integer> productCodes = new HashSet<>();
        for(Product product: products){
            productCodes.add(product.getCode());
        }
        return productCodes;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your solution is not-linear and too slow with significant amount of data.  just use straightforward approach:

```
public Map<Integer, List<Product>> getProductsByIndex (List<Product> products){
    Map<Integer, List<Product>> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

    for(Product product: products){
        List<Product> productsByCode = resultMap.get(product.getCode());
        if (productsByCode == null) {
           productByCode = new ArrayList();
           resultMap.put(product.getCode(), productByCode);
        }
        productsByCode.add(product);    
    }
    return resultMap;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Java 8 solution :

```
Map<Integer, List<Product>> productsByCode  = products.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getProductCode));
```

Comment: I want to upvote this for elegance but I've no idea if it would work. Note to self, read up on the new java 8 functional stuff :)

Comment: Upvote applied, although it will take a while before everyone (or even most people) will be able to switch to this solution over mine.

Comment: I'd also be interested to see some performance comparisons - although I don't have time to do any at the moment.

Comment: Be less on stackoverflow and you will have a lot of time to go with Java 8 :))

Comment: Well, for a lot of people it's a matter of what your employer does, not what you chose to do (if you want to apply new tech productively).

Answer (score 4):

```
for (Product p: products) {
    List<Product> l = productsByCode.get(p.getCode());
    if (l == null) {
       l = new ArrayList<>();
       productsByCode.put(p.getCode(), l);
    }
    l.add(p);
}
```

That's all you need :)

Comment: Correct answer, but you should probably note that `productsByCode` is your result, instead of `resultMap` in the original code.

Comment: +1, maybe not so *elegant* like the Java 8 solution below, but easy to understand at first glance

Comment: @user1781290: It also works in pretty much every Java version currently in use, significantly improving the usefulness of this snippet/answer.

Comment: @elusive Right. I just wanted to point out, that I prefer simpler solutions over code that is difficult to understand when you revisit it a month or a year later.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/) you can convert products to a `ListIterable` and use the `groupBy()` method.

```
ListMultimap<Integer, Product> productsByCode =
    products.groupBy(Product::getProductCode);
```

A `Multimap<Integer, Product>` is conceptually similar to `Map<Integer, List<Product>>` but it's optimized for this use-case. You can still call `get()` to get the products with a particular code.

```
ListIterable<Product> productsWithCode = productsByCode.get(someProductCode);
```

But by using a `Multimap`, you don't have to worry about null. `get()` will return an empty collection when the product code doesn't exist, rather than null. `Multimap` also has convenience methods like `containsKeyAndValue()`.

```
boolean b = productsByCode.containsKeyAndValue(someProductCode, product);
```

If you cannot convert products from a `List` to a `ListIterable`, then you can use `ListAdapter` to get the same API.

```
ListMultimap<Integer, Product> productsByCode =
    ListAdapter.adapt(products).groupBy(Product::getProductCode);
```

With versions of Java before Java 8, the method reference becomes an anonymous `Function`.

```
ListMultimap<Integer, Product> productsByCode =
    products.groupBy(new Function<Product, Integer>()
    {
        @Override
        public Integer valueOf(Product product)
        {
            return product.getProductCode();
        }
    });
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse collections.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
Map<Integer, List<Product>> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Product product : products) {
    List<Product> productList = resultMap.get(product.getCode());
    if (productList == null) {
        productList = new ArrayList<>();
        resultMap.put(product.getCode(), productList);
    }
    productList.add(product);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Map<Integer, List<Product>> getProductsByIndex (List<Product> products){
    Map<Integer, List<Product>> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

    for(Product product : products) {
        if(!resultMap.containsKey(product.getProductCode()) {
            resultMap.put(product.getProductCode(), new ArrayList<Product>();
        }

        resultMap.get(product.getProductCode()).add(product);
    }

    return resultMap;

}
```